# Kubernetes network utilization metrics

Tags: kubernetes, heapster, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster GKE on Google Compute Engine GCE.
Through Heapster I am able to get different [network metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/storage-schema.md) such as sent or received bytes, or error rate.

However, in order to better understand my application (Pods) bottlenecks, it would be essential to understand how utilized is the Node's network. Is it possible to query Network Utilization, otherwise what metrics do indicate my network health?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556376/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-connection-to-a-pod-in-a-kubernetes-cluster) is a similar problem. I believe network metrics on pod level are not available yet, as this is rather tricky to realize for all kube-proxy modes (github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/9125).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a direct way on your side to monitor the [VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/) but there are some tools that might help you to check that it is behaving as expected.

The only documented limit on VPC networks are the [egress throughput caps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps) which will depend  on the number of cores the nodes have.

You can see the graphs for “Networks Bytes” and “Network Packets” in your Google Cloud Console. They can be retrieve by going to:

Cloud Console -> Instance Groups ->  Managed_Intance_Group_Name

or

Cloud Console->  VM Instances -> Node_Name

Network graphs for the pools and the nodes can also be found in the Stackdriver Account

(https://app.google.stackdriver.com) -> Resources -> Container Engine -> Cluster Name

Analyzing those graphs might help you to determine if your traffic is being throttled.

To obtain additional visibility you could also use cAdvisor or other tools mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/)